# Rails: 'match' function in routes.rb escaping slashes in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I am new to ruby and rails. Here in routes.rb i have added the following line:

```
match 'check/' => "home#index"
```

When i hit url with server running on port 3000:

```
localhost:3000/check/
```

it works fine, but if i give url

```
localhost:3000/////////////////check////////////////////
```

it also works fine which should not be the case. With url

```
localhost:3000/////////////check////d//////
```

it says

> No route matches [GET] "/check/d"

It means it is escaping slashes, why this is happening and how to resolve  it. Also help me to know if we can make urls using regular exressions on rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding regular expressions in routes:

```
match '/:id' => 'posts#show', :constraints => {:id => /^\d/}
```

Will put a constraint on the id to be only digits.

Comment: thanks for this, but can you tell me about the above problem of slashes which is occuring